# Hook api call in a parent process

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

So the current situation is this:
.exe has a direct dependency ( in the IAT ) of dll1
dll1 does LoadLibrary dll2.
I want to hook ( and override ) a winapi of the exe from dll2.
I tried hooking both IAT and using [minhook](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44326/MinHook-The-Minimalistic-x-x-API-Hooking-Libra) . But the problem is that with both I actually hook the api of dll1, not the exe.
If i hook something like MessageBox, if i call it from dll1 it works, if i call it from the exe it doesn't ( it calls original MessageBox not my hooked one ).

Comment: Since the EXE and DLLs are all in the same address space, DLL2 has access to the EXE's IAT, if it knows where to look, and that is not hard to figure out.  It sounds like you are simply not hooking the EXE's IAT at all, only the DLL1's IAT. I'm surprised DLL2 was even able to find DLL1's IAT, that takes more work to find than the EXE's IAT. But you haven't shown any code demonstrating how you are performing the actual hooking, so noone can explain what you are doing wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Microsoft detours or easy hook? I have tried both and they work well.
Easyhook : https://easyhook.github.io/

Comment: I think EasyHook is for c# only, no? Detours needs a licence ( and the express doesn't support x64 code, which i need )

Comment: EasyHook supports injecting assemblies built for .NET Framework 3.5 / 4.0+ as well as native DLLs. Yes detours needs licence if you need x64 support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the compiler for your DLL is creating stub functions, (that forward to the real function) and the hooking tool is hooking the stub and not the real function.
So when the EXE is calling the function, it obviously doesn't use your stub, and call the real, unhooked function.

The simple solution: get a pointer to the real function using GetProcAddress, and hook it.

Comment: dll1 implements itself some of those api ( for example send, recv ), dll2 hooks send, recv. When dll1 calls send, it calls the hooked function. When the exe calls send, it's not hooked.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing. what is your API that you want to hook? who is implementing it? I'd load the program in the debugger, and follow, in asm level, to see how these calls behave before and after hook.